# How to stop Jasmine test after x seconds testing a recursive function

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I have a function which I want to test but I want to stop the test after x seconds.

```js
describe("if provided with a invalid sudoku grid", () => {
  it("should timeout", () => {
    const result = solve(unSolveAble);
  });
});
```

I've tried using `setTimeout` with

- `fail()`
- throwing a error `throw Error()`

but did not succeed to stop the test after a x seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
describe("if provided with a invalid sudoku grid", () => {
  it("should timeout", (done) => {
    let result = undefined;
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(result).toBeUndefined();
      done();
    }, 5_000); // after 5 second, you can decide the time
    result = solve(unSolveAble);
  });
});
```

The `done` callback will be called telling the test that the test should be done after 5 seconds.

Comment: If I try the `setTimeout` without calling the `solve` function the test fails after **5 seconds** as expected. But when I do call the `solve` function it does not fail after 5 seconds. Any clue?

Comment: That means that `solve` completes within `5 seconds`, no? I have also made an edit where we check the value of `result` to still be undefined.

Comment: `solve` keeps on running, I tried using your edit but no success. I also tried a dummy function which returns a value after **7** seconds. This function does get 'canceled' by the **5** second timeout.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.